# An invisible object in a variable causing $variable.count to return wrong result

Tags: powershell, variables

I have a $Variable containing 3 objects and what seems to be an invisible object that is interupting my script result because i am using $variable.Count which is returning 4 and not 3!

it looks something like this:

```
 $counter2 = $managedpaths.Count
```

result = 4

but i when call the variable like this:

```
$managedpaths
```

it give back three objects with an empty space in the first line like so:

```
*here it shows nothing at all, just empty space*
sites
help
projects
```

how can i ignore the first line when using the `.count` operator?

P.S: the invisible object is unknown and therefor should not be deleted!

Comment: The first object is probably a `$Null`, you can exclude it as follows: `$managedpaths =  $managedpaths | ?{$_}`, but you better find out where it comes from and avoid it from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know where $managedpaths came from.  You can do something like this:

```
PS C:\users\me> ';1;2;3' -split ';' -ne ''
1
2
3
```

Comment: [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) is probably easier and will cover more unexpected situations.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it solved my problem so easily... p.s: the $Managedpaths variable is a normal Url path and comes from this: **$Managedpaths = Get-SPManagedPath -WebApplication $Portal | Select-Object -Exp Name** where $portal is a sharepoint site Url looking something like this **http:/datsmysite.test-site.com/**